# How to avoid and recover shell command history from an unwanted incursion of non-printable characters?

Tags: bash, command-history, special-characters

```
$ history
...
  242  yum whatprovides */bin/xdotool
  243  yum provides */bin/xdotool
  244  yum provides xdotool
  245  yum whatprovides xdotool
  246  yum whatprovides xdotool
```

At the prompt:

`up`

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# yum whatprovides xdotool
```

`up`

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# yum whatprovidesxdotool
```

`up`

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# yumtprovidesxdotool
```

`up`

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# yumtprovides*/bin/xdotool
```

`up`

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# yumwhattprovides*/bin/xdotool
```

Note that in the first recalled command there is a non-printable character which I am representing with `☐` (unicode box character) which is invisible in my terminal and does not take up a character space. In my terminal I see this:

```
yum whatprovides xdotool
```

NOT this:

```
yum whatprovides ☐xdotool
```

Using `cat -A`:

```
$ history | cat -A
...
 246  yum whatprovides M-BM-^Vxdotool $
```

I am running Cygwin `mintty` on Windows 10 with a shell connection to Fedora 29.

I am using system defaults.

```
$ echo $PS1
[\u@\h \W]\$
```

I think this is related to:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31643/81989

> When it's in PS1, bash counts the number of characters that get
>   printed so that it can correctly redraw when you scroll through your
>   history. That's why bash has the [ and ] special characters—they
>   tell bash that the enclosed characters are not printable, which helps
>   bash figure out how to redraw the prompt when necessary.

I believe that this non-printable character in my history that is what's causing it to bug out.

I am interested in understanding HOW and WHY this happened but I also want to know:

- What options are available or recovery without purging my history
- Can Bash be configured to discard these characters from the command history to avoid this from happening in the future?
- Is there a way to identify what the offending character is?

As an aside, what are the use cases where preserving these non-printable characters in the command history is advantageous? Whenever I encounter this problem it's always a nuisance.

Comment: possibly this would be of interest? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41739/keep-only-successful-commands-in-bash-history

Comment: This seems very similar to [your other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535724/how-to-avoid-bash-from-accepting-non-printable-characters-at-the-prompt) ...?

Comment: @JeffSchaller This question is specifically about Bash's command history and how to recover from this state. The other question is on how to avoid non-printable characters from being entered at the prompt to avoid reaching this state. I felt that they were unique enough to be split into separate questions.