# How to avoid bash from accepting non-printable characters at the prompt?

Tags: bash, terminal, terminal-emulator, special-characters

I recently ran a command at my shell:

```
# yum whatprovides xdotool
Error: No Matches found
```

However, my package manager actually has this package:

```
# yum whatprovides xdotool
xdotool-1:3.20150503.1-7.fc29.x86_64 : Fake keyboard/mouse input
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Provide    : xdotool = 1:3.20150503.1-7.fc29
```

The problem is that I somehow entered a non-printable character at the prompt which was invisible to me.

Representing this invisible character with `☐` (the unicode box character), this is what I typed:

```
yum whatprovides ☐xdotool
```

But this is what I saw:

```
yum whatprovides xdotool
```

Is there a way to tell bash to disallow the user from entering non-printable characters from the prompt? Are there any use cases where someone would actually want to do this?

And is this a failure of my terminal emulator for not providing a visual indicator?

Comment: I don't think bash can easily know whether a character will show up visibly on the terminal. I blame this on your terminal emulator.